# Stripe/Firebase paymentIntent is not defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I've create simple app with payment Gpay/card with flutter and firebase. But now in firebase function I'v got this error: paymentIntent is not defined. Can someone give a tip how to deal with this?

This is my function

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_');

exports.StripePI = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const fee = (req.query.amount/100) | 0;
  const stripeVendorAccount = 'acct_';

  stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount: req.query.amount,
                currency: req.query.currency,
                payment_method: req.query.paym,
                confirmation_method: 'automatic',
                confirm: true,
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                //application_fee_amount: fee,
                description: req.query.description,
              }, {
                stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount
              },
              function(err, paymentIntent) {
                // asynchronously called
                const paymentIntentReference = paymentIntent;

if (err !== null){
  console.log('Error payment Intent: ', err);
  res.send('error');
} else {
  console.log('Created paymentintent: ', paymentIntent);
  res.json({
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent, 
    stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount});
}});

    console.log(paymentIntent.status);


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your final `console.log(paymentIntent.status);` is defined outside of the block where `paymentIntent` is declared, so it can't reach it.

To fix it, move `console.log(paymentIntent.status);` into the block above it:

```
exports.StripePI = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const fee = (req.query.amount / 100) | 0;
    const stripeVendorAccount = 'acct_';

    stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: req.query.amount,
            currency: req.query.currency,
            payment_method: req.query.paym,
            confirmation_method: 'automatic',
            confirm: true,
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            //application_fee_amount: fee,
            description: req.query.description,
        }, {
            stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount
        },
        function(err, paymentIntent) {
            // asynchronously called
            const paymentIntentReference = paymentIntent;

            if (err !== null) {
                console.log('Error payment Intent: ', err);
                res.send('error');
            } else {
                console.log('Created paymentintent: ', paymentIntent);
                res.json({
                    paymentIntent: paymentIntent,
                    stripeAccount: stripeVendorAccount
                });
            }
            console.log(paymentIntent.status);
        });
});
```

As you can maybe see above, I find it easier to catch problems such as this if the code is consistently indented. If you're having a hard time maintaining a consistent style, consider using a tool like Prettier or (as I did above) [beautifier.io](https://beautifier.io/).

Comment: This is the correct answer. Further to this I would also move `console.log(paymentIntent.status)` to within the else block right above where it is here. If there's an error creating a paymentIntent it will be `null`, and you'd still likely get a runtime warning as you'll be attempting to access `status` on a null object.